# Disable Constructor Info Box In Visual Studio Code for Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm working in Visual Studio Code on Flutter and I have too many info-boxes. When I complete a Widget with tab, this info box comes up displaying way too much info on the Widget I am not looking for. How do you disable this? I've disabled all code snippet helpers through the editor but it doesn't stop the behavior.

[image: Multiple Boxes to remove]

Answer (score 0):

This popup is called "Parameter Hints". You can prevent it from appearing automatically (so it only appears if you press Cmd+Shift+Space) by turning off this setting here:

[image: VS Code Parameter Hints setting]